# How to GET multiple values in php?

Tags: php, get

I have a url like this

`http://example.com/index.php?&item_name_1=productnamex&quantity_1=1&amount_1=0&item_number_1=2&on0_2=thumb&option_index_2=1&item_name_2=productnamex&quantity_2=1&amount_2=0&item_number_2=2&on0_2=thumb&option_index_2=1&item_name_3=productnamexx&quantity_3=1&amount_3=0&item_number_3=3&on0_3=thumb&option_index_3=1.....`

that sends to a page the values of a shopping card. I want to GET the values item_name_x, quantity_x, amount_x where x the number of each product, group and print them like

Product 1 name - Product 1 Quantity - Product 1 Amount 
Product 2 name - Product 2 Quantity - Product 2 Amount 
Product 3 name - Product 3 Quantity - Product 3 Amount
......

I can't make any change to the page who produce the url.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Can you show the code you tried making this work with?

Comment: So... you want to do a simple $_GET['productname'] and so on?

Comment: I tried '$_GET["item_name_1"]' etc but every time the number of products in url is different and i don't know how to get the values for different number of products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a really bad design, poor you have to deal with it. However, if you're sure that the query string will always be consistent (i.e.: each group will always be complete: name-quantity-amount) you can try this:

```
$i = 1;
while (isset($_GET['item_name_'.$i])) {
  $name = $_GET['item_name_'.$i];
  $qty = $_GET['quantity_'.$i];
  $amt = $_GET['amount_'.$i];
  ... // do whatever you want with those 3
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
<?php 
$count=count($_GET);
for($i=1;$i=$count;$i++)
{?>
Product <?php $i;?> name - Product <?php echo $i?> Quantity - Product <?php echo $i?> Amount
<?php }?>
```